# Spread operator in PhpStorm

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, phpstorm, webstorm, spread-syntax

my problem is that PhpStorm "red strikes" a spread operator in this line : `if(Math.max(...yearstab) !== (date + 2))`. I'd like to know if you found a way to prevent problems like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since spread operator was introduced in the [ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition, ECMA-262)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array-initializer) you need to tell PhpStorm that you're using this version.

You can do this by going in the project settings, "Languages & Frameworks", "JavaScript" and set "JavaScript language version" to "ECMAScript 6"

[image: Screenshot]